# How to send email from menu?

Tags: java, android, email

How do you send email through a "menu" button? I have inflated a menu with an option called "send". Once pressed it should open the Intent.ACTION_SEND and then the user can choose to send me an email.

I know how to achieve this via a Button and OnClickListener. But not through a menu. The code pasted below does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

CustomStoreActivity:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.customstore_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.send:

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "myemail@myemail.com" });
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Adding new shop to MinuteMap");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "nll");
        // shopName + shopTimeM1);

        break;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: Found the answer:

    startActivity(i); 

I made the Intent and didn't tell it to start it. Thank you #android-dev - user: 'readme' in pointing that out.

Comment: I added answer also please do paste your answer if get solution. so that it could be helpful to others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use below code :::

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "myemail@example.com" });
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Adding new shop to MinuteMap");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "nll"); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thank you Agarwal, that is exactly what I did. I just added the "startActivity(i)". Silly mistake, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code,

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/html");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { "abc@xyz.com" });

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    "Subject of the Mail");
            emailIntent
                    .putExtra(
                            android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                            "This is my sample Mail");
            emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```